# Xcode 8, Crashlytics and push notifications during test

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, crashlytics

I have one iOS app which I distribute with Crashlytics Beta. When I distribute it, I sign the app with my Ad hoc certificate. I dont get push notifications in this version.

If I upload the app to iTunes Connect and distribute it with TestFlight, push notification works!

The difference is, that the app is signed with my App Store certificate. Also, our push server (Pushwoosh) is setup with production envrionment.

It seems that the certificate signing or something else has an influence in the push notifications, but I cant figure out what.

The `aps-environment` is still set to `development` when distributing to iTunes Connect.

Any thoughts? The problem arose after updating to Xcode 8 and supporting iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Xcode 8 archiving with *Automatically manage signing off* (Target - General - Signing) and selecting your provisioning profiles manually?

Comment: Yes I did both. But I need the Ad Hoc to distribute via Crashlytics and the push notification doesnt work if the push environment is set to production.

Answer (score 1):

My setup might have been wrong, so I changed it.

When distributing to test regardless of app target/release I now set the push server (Pushwoosh) to use development / sandbox environment.
So now I only use one specific app target/release for App Store releases.

The reason why I used to use the same for App Store as for test is to ensure that everything works! But I cannot do that now.

Answer (score 1):

Does your entitlements file include the aps-environment entitlement? Are you exporting your ad-hoc and app store builds by archiving first? If both archived apps have the aps-environment entitlement, then your exported apps should as well.

Comment: yes I have and both aps-environment entitlements value is "development" which is kind of strange.